# Handling Webchat with existing NodeJS Bot

Tags: botframework

I was building this bot using NodeJS. I was testing it with Skype and Embedded on a web page using an iFrame, everything was working fine. I was trying to achieve something, and here advised me that I should do it using DirectLine in order to use postActivity once the user is connected to the chat to send them a message when they connect.

Now when am reading the docs about the DirectLine API, it seems like it's a totally different thing from what am doing, and the docs aren't showing the differences or the "When to use" DirectLine.

For example, in my NodeJS application, am just following the NodeJS SDK with the dialogs, session.send(), session.sendTyping(), etc..

My question is: does it mean when I want to use DirectLine that I need to replace this whole NodeJS bot code with Activities? Am confused about how I would use DirectLine along with my an existing application. What will happen with the Skype channel? Do I replace everything with activities? Would I be using session.sendTyping or activities for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) is just the term used for any event that has been processed by one of the bot framework channels. Your bot only ever speaks in activities, so no changes are needed to the serverside code in order to enable directline to communicate with your bot properly.

What you might need to change is the utilization of the iframe. Webchat is powered by a directline channel by default, but since the iframe is an all in one embed and it's not really possible to access the directline.

That user is asking you to use [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline) method which looks something like this:

```
botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({secret: "<secret>"});

BotChat.App({
     botConnection:  botConnection,
     user: { id: 'User', name: 'user'},
     bot: { id: 'botid' },
     resize: 'detect'
   }, document.getElementById("bot"));
```

to initialize your bot in your website, in order to enable the following backchannel:

```
botConnection
  .postActivity({
    from: { id: '<user>' },
    value: "text",
    type: 'event',
    name: "ConversationUpdate"
  })
  .subscribe(id=> console.log("stuff" + id))
```

However if you are having trouble enabling a welcome message from the frontend, consider following [this blogpost](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/) on the topic, which explains utilizing listeners on serverside for user connection events. Regardless, you should be OK without needing to rewrite anything in terms of trying to enable support for activities, as they are already being utilized.

Comment: thanks, but this will work for webchat, how about other channels? What if I want to implement backchannel to send messages to users once they open the conversation on Skype?

Comment: Backchannel is a frontend concept so it's really only implementable in locations where you have full control over the website itself. In other channels cases getting a "conversation open" event depends. Some send a message whenever a user joins/opens a conversation and some don't. In Skype's case it sends an event along the lines of `ContactRelationUpdate` when a user opens a new conversation.

Comment: you said that I don't need to modify my server side code. In my server side code, I use session.send("any text here"); however according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#reply-to-the-users-message .. I should be using post to /v3/activities in order to respond to the user. It's a little bit confusing in the docs as to when to use session.send and when to utilize the REST APIs..

Comment: `session.send()` is something of an alias for the REST API itself and its handling the POST for your behind the scenes. You're already utilizing the REST API when you use `session.send()` and generally you shouldn't have to call the REST API itself if you are using one of the SDKs (as opposed to making a bot in a different, non-sdk language and setting up the API calls yourself.)

Comment: Hi Mark B, I tried installing 'botframework-webchat', and doing something like: import { Chat , DirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat', when I do Chat.DirectLine, the compiler tells me there's no members of Chat as DirectLine

Comment: I'll mark this one as answered, I will write another question for the new problem and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, please check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319992/botframework-map-is-not-a-function