# Botframework - Map is not a function

Tags: botframework

I am trying to embed a DirectLine web chat into my React component, this is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
// import styles from './MyChatClient.module.scss';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { Chat, DirectLine, App } from 'botframework-webchat'

export default class MyChatClient extends React.Component<MyChatClient, {}> {
  botConnection: DirectLine;
  _chat: Chat;
  constructor(props: MyChatClient) {

    super(props);
    this.botConnection = new DirectLine({ secret: "G2EBXPrggQcHECliix....." });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<MyChatClient> {
    return (
      <Chat
        adaptiveCardsHostConfig={{}}
        botConnection={this.botConnection}
        user={{ id: 'User', name: 'user' }}
        bot={{ id: 'botid' }}
        resize='detect'

      />


    )
  }
}
```

However, I getting this error in the browser:

> Store.ts:676 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: action$.ofType(...).map
>   is not a function
>       at updateSelectedActivityEpic (Store.ts:676)

Is there anything specific I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the React sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/react/index.html ?

Comment: @EricDahlvang Yes, that's the sample I was following actually. I am not sure what I need to do except for the query params thing, which I don't think would have an affect.

Comment: @EricDahlvang , Plus, if I want to do the queryparams as in the post, I do something like Chat.queryParams(location.search) .. and it says queryparams doesn't exist on type Chat.. 

I believe there's something missing here, can we have some details docs for this?